# Error Delphi XE2 - Exception class $C00000005

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-xe2, access-violation

I am getting this error will debugging a project, which used to be in Delphi 7 and I have been upgrading to Delphi XE2, the same error happens in several methods.

```
First chance exception at $006DC660. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x006dc660 read of address 0xffffffff'
```

This is one of the methods:

```
PFI = ^TFI;           
TFI = record
Id         : TToken;
Name       : TName;
Parameters : string;
end;

function TListFI.IsIn(S: PChar): PFI;

  function SearchName2(Item: PFI):Boolean;
  var N1, N2: PChar;
  begin
    N1:= StrNew(Item^.Name);
    N2:= StrNew(S); //Here is the issue
    SearchName2:= (StrComp(StrUpper(N1), StrUpper(N2)) = 0);
    StrDispose(N1);
    StrDispose(N2);
  end;

begin
  IsIn:= PFI(FirstThat(@SearchName2));
end;
```

I have googled and I found someone describing a similar problem, and he affirms that when the incremental linker is disabled it works, can someone tell me what and where is it or give some advice to solve this situation.

[EDIT]

Removing the @ now gives me the following error in IsIn:= PFI(FirstThat(SearchName2));

```
E2010 Incompatible types: 'TObject' and 'PFI'
```

I am adding the FirstThat procedure to see if it may help.

```
TFuncionColeccion = function (Elemento: TObject): Boolean;

function TColeccion.FirstThat (Rutina: TFuncionColeccion): TObject;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  For i:=0 to Count-1 do
    if Rutina(Items[i]) then
    begin
      FirstThat:=Items[i];
      exit;
    end;
  FirstThat:=nil;
end;
```

Comment: What led you to use `StrNew`? First step I would take would be to expunge that from my codebase.

Comment: I received this project and it has being in the hands of several students (I am one too). What could be used insted and why expunge it?    I'll add the addresses.

Comment: Heap allocation of null terminated strings requires careful memory management. Your code misses the requisite try/finally loops to protect against leaks. In today's Delphi you would use `string`. You can convert `PAnsiChar` and `PWideChar` directly to `string` with simple assignment,

Comment: @sandiego - to me, the mixing of pointer and managed types in the same record declaration suggests the author didn't really know what they were doing. If I were you, I'd look to refactor the code and remove the explicit pointer use completely - `StrNew` and friends are rather crappy precursors to the heap-managed `string` type introduced in Delphi 2 back in 1996. Where there are still reasons to use the `PChar` type when appropriate, amongst them will not be when you just want to make a case insensitive comparison of two strings.

Comment: I am still struggling with this problem, question edited, but if is not a problem can someone explain me why is the original function working on Delphi 7, but in Delphi XE2 I get this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is (and always has been) an error to call local (nested) procedures by pointer, which is clearly what your `FirstThat` function does. The compiler has to do special things with the stack to call local functions and give them access to the parent scope's variables (`S` in your code), but the compiler can only know to do those special things when the local function is called directly. The compiler cannot know that the argument to `FirstThat` will be a local function, so it doesn't include the special code when `FirstThat` invokes the pointed-to function.

The bottom line is that the stack inside the function doesn't get set up the way it's supposed to, and that means any number of strange symptoms may appear. You'll have to use some other way. Maybe make `SearchName2` be a two-argument function, and then write `FirstThat` to accept `S` as a parameter that it can forward to the function argument.

You shouldn't need to use the `@` operator when constructing a function pointer. When you do, the compiler tends to skip type checking, which is what allowed you to pass a local function pointer to `FirstThat` in the first place. When the function you're passing really matches the required prototype, the compiler will allow you to pass it without the `@` operator.

Answer (score 4):

You are reporting an access violation in

```
StrNew(S)
```

where `S` is of type `PChar`. The explanation for that, with probability very close to 1, is that `S` is not in fact a pointer to null terminated array of `WideChar`.

In Delphi 7, `PChar` is an alias for `PAnsiChar`. That is a pointer to null terminated array of `AnsiChar`, i.e. 8 bit characters. In Delphi XE2, `PChar` is an alias for `PWideChar`, a pointer to null terminated array of `WideChar`, i.e. 16 bit characters.

It helps to understand what `StrNew` does. It walks the array until it finds a null character. For 8 bit text that is a single zero byte. For 16 bit text, the null is a zero 16 bit word. Then it allocates a new block of memory of the same length as the input string, and makes a copy into that new memory. The source code is:

```
function StrNew(const Str: PWideChar): PWideChar;
var
  Size: Cardinal;
begin
  if Str = nil then Result := nil else
  begin
    Size := StrLen(Str) + 1;
    Result := StrMove(WideStrAlloc(Size), Str, Size);
  end;
end;
```

The only plausible failure mode is that when `StrLen` walks the array, it attempts an invalid memory read. And that can only happen if your input parameter is invalid. In other words, this must be a programming error on your part.

One possible explanation is that you are in fact passing 8 bit text to this function despite promising to pass 16 bit text. An easy mistake to make, especially if you are not yet fully familiar with the Unicode change. The 8 bit text has a zero terminator, but the byte that follows happens not to be zero. Or the zero byte falls at an odd numbered offset from the start. And then `StrNew` continues walking the buffer, but now it is off the end and it so happens that it doesn't find a zero word before overrunning into an address that has not been allocated. And that is an access violation.

If that is so then solution will be either:

- Change the function's parameter to be of type `PAnsiChar`, and fix the dubious casting at the call site.
- Pass the function 16 bit text as it requires.

In your update you include the address which cannot be read, `0xffffffff`. This is `-1` in hex. And that would seem to be the most prosaic of errors. Your pointer is completely bogus! Your exact error message can be reproduced with this code: `StrNew(PChar(-1))`.

I don't have enough information here to tell you why your pointer is bogus. Hopefully you've learnt some debugging and diagnostic techniques that will enable you to solve the problem. At least you now know that the error is in your code.

Assuming that BuscaName2 and SearchName2 are one and the same thing, then you need look no further. Local procedures can only be called from a containing function. As @Rob correctly says, the use of @ with procedures is almost always incorrect and is a warning sign of serious problems with your code.

Comment: Hi. What exactly is "exception class $C0000005" ? What is this specific number?

Comment: @server it's the NT status code for access violation