# Passing a parameter in a nested function

Tags: delphi, parameter-passing, delphi-xe2, nested-function

I have this nested function and I want to modify SearchName2 to receive "S" as a parameter as a possible solution to the problem described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342177/error-delphi-xe2-exception-class-c00000005).

I am still learning Delphi and I'd appreciate any help, I've been searching for nested function examples and I can't find anything similar.

```
PFI = ^TFI;           
TFI = record
    Id         : TToken;
    Name       : TName;
    Parameters : string;
end;

function TListFI.IsIn(S: PChar): PFI;

  function SearchName2(Item: PFI):Boolean;
  var N1, N2: PChar;
  begin
    N1:= StrNew(Item^.Name);
    N2:= StrNew(S);
    SearchName2:= (StrComp(StrUpper(N1), StrUpper(N2)) = 0);
    StrDispose(N1);
    StrDispose(N2);
  end;

begin
  IsIn:= PFI(FirstThat(@SearchName2));
end;
```

Comment: If you didn't understand my answer, then you should have posted a comment requesting clarification. I could have shown you an example. Instead, you've apparently been struggling with this on your own for over a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob Kennedy gave you the solution in the [other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342177/error-delphi-xe2-exception-class-c00000005):

> make SearchName2 be a two-argument function, and then write FirstThat to accept S as a parameter that it can forward to the function argument.

You need to do what Rob told you to do, that is the solution, eg:

```
type
  TFuncionColeccion = function (Elemento: TObject; S: PChar): Boolean;

function TColeccion.FirstThat (Rutina: TFuncionColeccion; S: PChar): TObject;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  For i:=0 to Count-1 do
    if Rutina(Items[i], S) then
    begin
      FirstThat:=Items[i];
      exit;
    end;
  FirstThat:=nil;
end;
```

```
function SearchName2(Item: PFI; S: PChar):Boolean;
var
  N1, N2: PChar;
begin
  N1 := StrNew(Item^.Name);
  N2 := StrNew(S);
  SearchName2 := (StrComp(StrUpper(N1), StrUpper(N2)) = 0);
  StrDispose(N1);
  StrDispose(N2);
end;

function TListFI.IsIn(S: PChar): PFI;
egin
  IsIn := PFI(FirstThat(@SearchName2, S));
end;
```

With that said, you can get rid of the use of `StrNew()` and `StrDispose()` completely:

```
function SearchName2(Item: PFI; S: PChar):Boolean;
begin
  SearchName2 := (StrIComp(Item^.Name, S) = 0);
end;
```

Comment: I understand what has to be done, but I don't know how to do it. Even more I don't know why is there a problem in the first place because S should "exist" for the inner function, apparently it doesn't.

Comment: You did not listen to what Rob explained to you about how the inner function's call stack gets set up. You are bypassing the compiler's ability to call the inner function correctly, so you are causing side effects.

Comment: @sandiego It is frustrating for us to have to repeat ourselves. Please do make sure that you read carefully the answers you get when you ask a question. It is somewhat galling to see this code again, like a bad smell that won't go away.

Comment: @Remy It would also help if you would avoid using @ to get function pointers. Untyped function pointers are what got us into this mess in the first place.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: or [turn off untyped pointers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/e/index.php?title=Type-checked_pointers_(Delphi))

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, both are required. And doing both has the happy benefit that the code in the question is rejected by the compiler.